# Way to Automate Pressing of Specific Button on Page Load?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automation, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to figure out a way to simply click on a specific button (which is an href) on a particular page when it loads, via a userscript written in Javascript within Tampermonkey. It seems straightforward enough, but I haven't gotten any of my code to work, after multiple iterations.

Here is the full source code of the href and button that I want pressed:

```
<span data-react-class="require('reactComponents/workPipeline/SubmitAcceptTaskForm')['SubmitAcceptTaskFormLink']" data-react-props="{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;accept&quot;,&quot;refTag&quot;:&quot;w_wp_acpt_warning&quot;}"><span data-reactid=".4"><a href="#" data-reactid=".4.0">accept</a></span></span>
```

Here is the code that I have been trying to use (I have tested each individual line separately, and to no avail):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Accept Button WIP
// @include      https://worker.mturk.com/projects/*
// ==/UserScript==

location.href = document.querySelector("a[href='#']");

document.querySelector("a[data-reactid='.4.0']").click();

document.getElementsByClassName(".4.0")[0].click();

location.href = document.querySelector("a[href='#']");

location.data-reactid = document.querySelector("a[data-reactid='.4.0']").click();

document.querySelector("span[data-reactid='.4']").click();
```

And here is a screenshot of everything, including the DIVs that the button is contained within (the mouse is hovered over the necessary Accept button):

[image]

I'm not too sure with what I'm doing wrong. I thought one of the lines of code that I tried would have worked, but there is probably something I am overlooking in terms of syntax. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Have a wonderful day & night.

Comment: Am not an expert in usersripts or tampermonkey but are you executing the automation scripts (the ones to automate the click) after loading the page.ie,, `document.onready`

Comment: Any error is thrown in the console ?

Comment: or Maybe those ids are created dynamically on every page load.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell why it isn't working for you... For me it worked without problems with the following HTML test on localhost:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function check(){
    console.log('Hellow world');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span data-react-class="require('reactComponents/workPipeline/SubmitAcceptTaskForm')['SubmitAcceptTaskFormLink']" data-react-props="{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;accept&quot;,&quot;refTag&quot;:&quot;w_wp_acpt_warning&quot;}"><span data-reactid=".4"><a href="#" data-reactid=".4.0"  onclick='check()'>accept</a></span></span>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Autoclick
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        http://localhost/test.html
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.querySelector("a[data-reactid='.4.0']").click();
})();
```

For me, it worked without the autoexecutable function and I just added the [`@run-at` directive](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at) for good measure but it works without it.

The *"Hello World"* message appears on the console after page loading.

One tip is that most of the times, the code that you want to run on the userscript should run exactly the same from the console. This way, you can test live what works or not.

Comment: Your code works from the console, but for whatever reason I cannot get it to load on page start. I have a few error codes including: Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
    at CSRecorder.onQueryStateCompleted (chrome-extension://cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp/content_scripts/recorder.js:106:18)

Comment: Actually, the error no longer appears, and I now have just: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Again, the code works when it's inserted into the console but won't seem to run on page load. I will try to see if I have any conflicting apps or extensions.

Comment: Well I kinda figured out another solution to the problem. I ended up just doing document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")[0].click(); to another button, and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go a different route and select a different button. For whatever reason I couldn't get the code to activate on page load, but opted to select the other Accept button on the page via:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")[0].click();
```